# Is there an irc or twitch api function that let's me read all twitch chat messages from an already completed stream?

Tags: irc, twitch, twitch-api

I'm trying to read in every Twitch chat message on already completed Twitch streams, with the intent to summarize and get some statistics on the messages. What API do I use to pull down a list of chat messages from completed streams?

There seems to be an API for getting messages as they come along in currently live streams: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc. However, this only seems to work with currently live streams and it only gets the messages as they come along. Ideally, I want to be able to get a list of all chat messages from already completed streams instead. However I can't seem to find any API call that would let me do that, either as part of IRC or as part of the New Twitch API.

Comment: I don't think Twitch stores the chat messages anywhere, so you'd need to do your own aggregation of the live stream

Comment: I asked Twitch support, they said they don't have an API for it, so yeah, I would have to do my own aggregation of the live stream.